# Convert positions to offsets with collections API

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am given a sequence of filed lengths in a line, and want to convert it into offsets from the start of the line. Easy to do procedurally with accumulator, wonder what would be the functional way. Quick solution is:

```
scala> val positions = Array(9,10,15,4)
positions: Array[Int] = Array(9, 10, 15, 4)

scala> val offsets = positions.zipWithIndex.map(t => positions.take(t._2).sum)
offsets: Array[Int] = Array(0, 9, 19, 34)
```

This is obviously sub-optimal as it computes offset for every element from scratch. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
positions.scanLeft(0){ _+_ }
```

If you wan to drop the last element:

```
positions.scanLeft(0){ _+_ }.init
```